# Splitting one column into two columns in SQL Server CE

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, split, sql-server-ce

I am doing a project with VS2010 **using C#.**

I have a local database (.sdf file). Here is the example content of my database:

Column1

```
Ned Stark
Tyrion Lannister
Daenerys Targaryen
Robert Baratheon
```

What I am trying to do is split names and surnames into two different columns, like this:

**Names** 
                        **Surnames**

```
Ned               Stark
Tyrion            Lannister
Daenerys          Targaryen
Robert            Baratheon
```

Since I'm using **SQL Server CE 3.5 Edition**, LEFT, MID functions didn't work for me. So, how would I do that?

Comment: Question "[dividing-one-column-into-two-columns-in-sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985147/dividing-one-column-into-two-columns-in-sql)" is a lot like this question but asked about an hour after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING([Name], 0, CHARINDEX(' ', [Name], 0)) [FirstName],
       SUBSTRING([Name], CHARINDEX(' ', [Name], 0) + 1, LEN([Name])) [LastName]
```

EDIT:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING([Name], 0, CHARINDEX(' ', [Name], 0)) [FirstName],
       SUBSTRING([Name], CHARINDEX(' ', [Name], 0) + 1, LEN([Name])) [LastName] 
FROM
(
    SELECT 'Ned Stark' [Name] UNION 
    SELECT 'Tyrion Lannister' [Name] UNION
    SELECT 'Daenerys Targaryen' [Name] UNION
    SELECT 'Robert Baratheon' [Name]
) n
```

Just replace the part after from with you table and the column [Name] with you column.

Comment: Your query is missing from statement. Although I added "From mytable" at the end of your query, it didn't work. It did nothing.

Comment: If you run my edit part as is you should see the results from you question.

Comment: We have at least a hundred names in our column not only four. So, From statement of the edit part is problematic for me. What should i do?

Comment: @user733452 - Are you serious about your last question?, the `FROM` part of the answer is only an example, it should be replaced by your table, obviously.

Comment: yes i'm serious. i should write hundred rows in this way. i don't only have 4 rows.

Comment: No, you should replace everything after the FROM with you table.  And replace anywhere [Name] is in the select with the column you have with the people's full name.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING functions. Both of them are supported in CE according to [msdn](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174077.aspx).

Example:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(a, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', a)), 
    SUBSTRING(a, CHARINDEX(' ',a) + 1, LEN(a)) 
FROM
    (SELECT 'Random Joe' as a) t
```

Comment: When I run your query, I got the following error: There was an error parsing the query. [Token line number,Token line offset,,Token in error,,]