# Dividing one column into two columns in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, split, sql-server-ce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Splitting one column into two columns in SQL Server CE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984151/splitting-one-column-into-two-columns-in-sql-server-ce)

I am doing a project with VS2010 **using C#.**

I have a local database (.sdf file). Here is the example content of my database:

Column1

```
Frodo Baggins
Samwise Gamgee
Peregrin Took
Meriadoc Brandybuck
.
.
.
```

What I am trying to do is split names and surnames into two different columns, like this:

**Names** 
                        **Surnames**

```
Frodo             Baggins
Samwise           Gamgee
Peregrin          Took
Meriadoc          Brandybuck
.                 .
.                 .
.                 .
```

Since I'm using **SQL Server CE 3.5 Edition**, LEFT, MID functions didn't work for me. So, how would I do that?

Comment: Why you have C# tag? you want split it in your application or just want a query?

Comment: I want a query to use in my C# project, this is why i put that tag.

Comment: They are almost the exactly same, I bet its a homework question

Comment: @Erik Philips another question asked by this OP :)

Comment: I updated the question this is why I asked it again. I corrected the tables.

Comment: @user733452 The only thing changed between the two are the example names given. If you want to do this in the future then edit your original question instead of posting an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
DECLARE @YourTable table (Column1  varchar(50))
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('Frodo Baggins')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('Samwise Gamgee')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('Peregrin Took')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('Meriadoc Brandybuck')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('aa')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES ('aa bb cc')

SELECT
    LEFT(Column1,CHARINDEX(' ',Column1)) AS Names
    ,RIGHT(Column1,LEN(Column1)-CHARINDEX(' ',Column1)) AS Surnames
    FROM @YourTable

--both queries produce same output
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(Column1, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', Column1))
    ,SUBSTRING(Column1, CHARINDEX(' ',Column1) + 1, LEN(Column1)) 
FROM @YourTable
```

OUTPUT:

```
Names       Surnames
----------- -------------
Frodo       Baggins
Samwise     Gamgee
Peregrin    Took
Meriadoc    Brandybuck
            aa
aa          bb cc

(6 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: SQL Server Compact Edition has [`CHARINDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173376%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx), [`LEN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173257%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) and [`SUBSTRING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms174563%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx),  so the second query should work just fine.